# Wrong Palette of color when doing a supervised classification GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, random-forest, palette

I am doing a classification of forest and nonforest area using the random forest classifier. At the end of the process I am not getting the color separation, the classified image looks like this:
[image]

It had to be separated in green and red color, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. The final part of the code is:

var clasificador = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
features: total_samples,
classProperty: 'id',
inputProperties: bands})

var classificacion = imagen_final.select(bands).classify(clasificador)

var classVis = {
min: 0,
max: 10,
palette: ['00B200 ' ,'#ff0400']
};

Map.addLayer(classificacion, classVis)

But you can see the whole code here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/979e35d45e3aaca1e81da67c2bc40062

Comment: Have you tried the method from this tutorial https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization#rendering-categorical-maps ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your visualization parameters are wrong. You only have two classes and you are setting the min and max values to 0 and 10. Try this.

```
var classVis = {
  min: 1,
  max: 2,
  palette: ['00B200 ' ,'#ff0400']
};
```

The result now looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasn't aware of that!